# How to bind Image to just picked file from non app folder?

Tags: data-binding, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

User pick the image from file system. After it I want to show this image on page. What I should to do? Seems Image control hasn't access to picked files. Do I should copy it to app local storage? Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to copy file. `StorageFile` object has reference to the file stored in device. Check [File picker sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=234890) on MSDN and quickstart guide for [Accessing files with file pickers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465199).

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundBrush}">
    <Image x:Name="img" Stretch="None" />`
</Grid>
```

C#

```
private async Task SetImage()
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if(file != null)
    {
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();

        using(var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            bmp.SetSource(stream);
        }
        img.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```